# Create Choropleth Map in R

Tags: r, dataframe, choropleth

I'm in the process of trying to create a choropleth map in R utilizing some data in an Excel sheet that looks like the following

```
Zip    Frequency
64114  19
66061  23
64111  8
.
.
.
```

Basically, I want to create a map that shows the different zip codes, coded in a way that displays their frequencies. Reading around, it would seem that ggplot or choroplethr would be ideal for this task, but I'm having trouble finding details relating to my exact use case. Would anyone have any insight in how this would be easily achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some documentation on zip_choropleth: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/choroplethrZip/versions/1.5.0/topics/zip_choropleth

```
zip_choropleth(df, state_zoom="state", county_zoom=FIP, reference_map=TRUE, title="title", legend="legend)
```

You'll have to restructure your dataframe as it has to be in region, value format. Where region is a character and value is a number.

State_zoom should be "state" (i.e. for Ohio it would be state_zoom="ohio").

county_zoom should be FIPs codes. What I normally do is I create a list of the FIPs I need (which you can find here: https://transition.fcc.gov/oet/info/maps/census/fips/fips.txt). Then supply the name of the list in county_zoom.

You can also use reference_map=TRUE to add a google map underneath, but you will need to use ggmap, a google API key, and the get_map function.

I hope this helps you get started as your question was vague.